# I get in QGIS: "ERROR[25]: Error reading raster. Possibly the raster path contains unicode characters"

Tags: qgis, raster

[image: Error message screenshot]I have done clipping, and classified the land according to the various characteristics in QGIS.
But when I try to save the processed image to my local machine I get the following error message:

**`"ERROR[25]: Error reading raster. Possibly the raster path contains unicode characters"`**.

I don't know what to do.

Comment: Can you add a screen shot of the dialog box you are using for this operation.  Can you edit your post to include the proposed path of your output data?

Comment: yes, I have added the screenshot of the dialog box

Comment: Maybe try Team_A and not Team A (with a space) in the output name?

Comment: what is the path to your original raster?

Comment: This is the path for my original raster:

**E:\Downloads\assignment\projectArea\date\Landsat_8_data\clipped**

Comment: @GBG I did what you have said. Buti still the same problem.

Comment: That sounds like a bug.  Maybe upgrade (or downgrade) to an LTR version of QGIS if you are not running one now?